# How can I concatinate the eslint airbnb style guide into one file to copy into package.json?

Tags: javascript

If you look at these directories and quoted file contents you can see the structure of the style guide .js files and how they all load into eslint:

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules

```
//index.js

module.exports = {
  extends: [
    './rules/best-practices',
    './rules/errors',
    './rules/node',
    './rules/style',
    './rules/variables',
    './rules/es6',
    './rules/imports', // (my note) not needed as uses extra plugin
  ].map(require.resolve),
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  rules: {
    strict: 'error',
  },
};

// .eslintrc
{
  "extends": "./index.js",
  "rules": {
    // disable requiring trailing commas because it might be nice to revert to
    // being JSON at some point, and I don't want to make big changes now.
    "comma-dangle": 0,
    // we support node 4
    "prefer-destructuring": 0,
  },
}
```

I would like to concatinate all the files together so I can paste it into my package.json. How can I do this? I don't know node, I don't need all the other stuff in the NPM download, I would just like a permanent copy of the current style guide in one file in one place. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the instructions on installing eslint-config-airbnb-base: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base#eslint-config-airbnb-base-1, step 2 asks you to create a file `.eslintrc` in your project's root directory.

```
// .eslintrc
{
  "extends": "airbnb-base"
}
```

You don't need to concatenate any files to use eslint-config-airbnb-base. Install it and create `.eslintrc` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I do already have it working. I want to concatenate all the rules expect the imports (that needs the extra plugin) into one file to paste into package.json. I know eslint can read the rules from package.json, and I want them there rather than having multiple files all over my project directories. Also I can edit them all in one place... can you help? I am sure it is very basic for a node user to do this? cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and I have not tried this but it should work.
Just copy the rule files from the Airbnb repo into your repo and then create a new copy from their index.js file called something else like "my-eslint-rules.js" in your repo. The last step is to have an .eslintrc that refers to this new file with extends.